# ¿se puede hacer que un elemento la misma medida en height y en width pero solo conociendo el valor de uno de ellos?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

¿Cómo podría obtener el siguiente resultado?
quiero que un div tenga su height relacionado a su width, algo como lo siguiente:

```css
div {  
    width: 100%;  
    height: width - 10px;  
}
```

¿se puede lograr esto sin usar JS?

Comment: Hola, podrias especificar mejor la preguntar para tener una mejor comprension añadiendo codigo, de todas formas aqui te dejo una guia para mejorar las preguntas (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Saludos 

Comment: Por favor añade el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, esperas que el width y el heigth compartan el mismo valor? y la solución full css o sass (por las etiquetas)?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] e Inserta un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: @AnkiJedi ya esta mejor descrito el problema

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es asignar un valor a una propiedad como si se tratara de una variable pues *css* tiene una forma de asignar variables:

```
:root{ /* aca estoy declarando y asignando valor a las variables*/
    --widthVal:500px; 
    --gbColor:gray;
}
div{
    width : var(--widthVal); /*Con var() puedo llamar una variable*/
    height : calc(var(--widthVal) - 100px);
    background-color: var(--gbColor);
}
```

Estoy usando `px` para la demostración pero bien podrías usar cualquier otra unidad (aunque debes tomar en cuenta que con `%` se expandirá la altura según el `height` del padre)

Comment: no, me refiero a que el width tenga 90% y el height tenga lo que salga de width menos 10px, tomando en cuenta que la medida de el width puede cambiar en diferentes pantallas y no conocemos su valor

Comment: Vale, lo que buscas es establecer el valor de una propiedad en base al valor de otra propiedad de forma dinámica, en ese caso no se me viene a la cabeza una solución sin js... tal ves usando sass o less se pueda conseguir pero no es mi campo, sorry...